# I can not deduce this formula from an article...

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes

I do not understand the calculation of a certain article published in J. Chem. Phys. 137 (2012):

I have a continous time discrete state model with a total number of for example $N_0$ indistinguishable balls that can go into $n$ buckets. The number of balls in bucket $i$ is denoted by $a_i$. So one equation that holds, is the conservation of the total number of balls:

$$N_0=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i\ .$$

The total number of solutions is given by

$$M = {N_0+n-1 \choose n-1}\ .$$

A enumerating function of the solutions can be defined as

$$f(a_1,...,a_n)=1+\sum_{i=2}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{a_i}{N_0-j+i-1-\sum_{h=i+1}^{n}a_h\choose i-2}\ .$$

A ball can go from a bucket to another with a rate denoted as $k_ij$. The master equation of the problem is given by

$$\frac{dP(a_1,...,a_n)}{dt}=-\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_i k_{ij}\right)P(a_1,...,a_n)+
\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} (a_i+1) k_{ij} P(a_1,...,a_i+1,...,a_j-1,...,a_n)\right)\ .$$

So now we define a few properties of the system like the mean of balls in bucket $i$ and the second moment:

$$\langle a_i\rangle = \sum_{\text{all M states}}a_iP(a_1,...,a_n)=\sum_{g=1}^{M} a_i(f^{-1}(g))P(f^{-1}(g))\equiv\Pi_i N_0$$
$$s_{ii}=\sum_{\text{all M states}}a_i^2P(a_1,...,a_n)$$
$$s_{ij}=s_{ji}=\sum_{\text{all M states}}a_i a_j P(a_1,...,a_n)$$

Using the above equations the author of the article deduces a differential equation for the second moment,

$$\frac{ds_{ii}}{dt}=(-2s_{ii}+N_0\Pi_i)\sum_{j=1}^n k_{ij} + 
\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(2s_{ij}+N_0\Pi_j\right)k_{ji}\ ,$$

which I am not able to deduce. Maybe someone with a more mathematically trained eye can explain to me, how he deduced this formula, starting from the master equation.
A second differential equation was deduced, but I hope once I understood the first, the second can be deduced similarly,

$$\frac{ds_{ij}}{dt}=-s_{ij}\sum_{h=1}^n(k_{jh}+k_{ih})-N_0(\Pi_ik_{ij}+\Pi_jk_{ji})+s_{ii}k_{ij}+s_{jj}k_{ji}+\sum_{h=1,h\neq j,h\neq i}^n(s_{ih}k_{hj}+s_{jh}k_{hi})\ .$$

Comment: "A certain article" - namely?

Comment: Stochastic mapping of first order reaction networks: A systematic comparison of the stochastic and deterministic kinetic approaches
Lente, Gábor, The Journal of Chemical Physics, 137, 164101 (2012), DOI:http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.4758458